# Including a partial within existing partial - Express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, partials

I am using partials in my views but am wondering if it is possible to include another partial within an existing partial. It seems not at present but cannot find any information on if this is possible at present.

My current setup looks like this

```
views
  partials
    home
      section1
        file.ejs
  partial.ejs
home.ejs
```

So within my `home.ejs` file I can include my `partial.ejs` partial

```
<% include partials/partial %>
```

But within my `partial.ejs` I can't seem to include another partial

```
<% include home/section1/file %>
```

Has anyone done this ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't just try it yourself, and share the result with us? :)

Comment: I have, not working, hence the question :-)

Comment: This comment certainly doesn't answer/help your question, but I use a library named `express-handlebars`. It supports nested partials, I do suggest for you to check it out. https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars